# Oldstylefigure issue with lualatex and mathastext

Tags: fonts, luatex, mathastext

I'm trying to figure out what causes OSF to be selected in mathematics. Following is the MWE.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[9pt,fleqn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=Vollkorn Medium, BoldItalicFont=Vollkorn Medium Italic, Numbers={Proportional,Uppercase}]{Vollkorn}
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
123 \emph{123} % no problems here

\[\int_1^3 f(x)\] % problem here
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are using xetex or luatex (as you must be with `fontspec` you should never load `inputenc` (if you are using the 2014 version it warns and does nothing, older versions will break the document completely)

Comment: OK for the hint. But this is not the solution for the problem.

Comment: yes but I haven't the fonts so can't comment on your main problem:-)

Comment: I wasn't complaining about that. By the way vollkorn is free.

Comment: It works with XeLaTeX but not with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr Any idea why?

Comment: Not really but in the case of XeLaTeX, `mathastext` uses the `EU1` encoding and in the case of LuaLaTeX, it uses the `EU2` encoding. However, I don't know what that means, whether it has any significance, or why it happens. However, `mathastext` does basically tell you not to use it with unicode fonts for maths (pp 22- of the manual).

Comment: I guess that is just because EU1 is for XeLaTeX and EU2 is for LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr As this does not seem to be solely  a `mathastext`  issue I have added `fonts` and `luatex` tags.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** version `1.3n` of `mathastext` dated `2016/05/03` will have a patch for this `LaTeX+LuaTeX+luaotfload` issue. Ultimately, perhaps `LaTeX` will be updated to modify `\DeclareSymbolFont` to take into account the kind of modification implemented by `mathastext`, and then the `mathastext` patch will prove unneeded. I will also provide a patch to `url.sty` in an answer I will post to [Can't get oldstyle figures in url with lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264206/cant-get-oldstyle-figures-in-url-with-lualatex)

---

This appears not to be an issue with [mathastext](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) but rather one of `lualatex` in math mode. Here is some code to exhibit the font used for digits by `mathastext` in math mode. The output looks correct for both `xelatex` and `lualatex`  but for the latter the figures are oldstyle despite what I understand of the font descriptor.

```
\documentclass[9pt,fleqn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{iftex}

\setmainfont[BoldFont=Vollkorn-Medium.ttf, 
     ItalicFont=Vollkorn-Italic.ttf,
     BoldItalicFont=Vollkorn-BoldItalic.ttf,
     Numbers=Lining]{Vollkorn-Regular.ttf}%
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}

% additional check
%\MTseries{bx}\Mathastext

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\fontname\font\newline
1234567890 

\emph{\fontname\font\newline 1234567890}

% check the font used by mathastext

Here is the name of the font used for digits in math mode:

\[\hbox{\fontname\textfont\symmtoperatorfont}\]

This is the very same font as the one used for this text and digits 01234567890
but nevertheless we see old style figures in math mode:
\[1234567890\]
\end{document}
```

output for `xelatex`: (with the end of last sentence removed)

> [image: test with xetex]

output for `lualatex`:

> [image: test with luatex]