# Can't get oldstyle figures in url with lualatex

Tags: luatex, urls, oldstylenums, luaotfload

The following works with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
    \urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Libertine Serif}[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]
\begin{document}
\url{http://example.com/1234567890}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But not with `lualatex`:

[image]

Fix possible? Bug?

Comment: This is no `biblatex` matter, but rather one of the `url` package as `\url{http://example.com/1234567890}` in the document shows. Maybe it is a good idea to make the example even more minimal and remove `biblatex` as it is certainly not the culprit here.

Comment: @moewe Good catch - will do.

Comment: IIRC, this is a duplicate of an earlier posting (which, unfortunately, I can't seem to locate right away). At any rate LuaLaTeX (but not XeLaTeX) appears to process the argument of `\url` in quasi-math mode, and math mode uses only lining figures, no oldstyle figures. Juxtapose the output of `1234567890` and `\url{1234567890}` to see what I mean.

Comment: Found it: [How to make the `url` package respect fontspec font options (stylisticset) with LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250619/5001). In that posting, note that `\path` is an alias for `\url`.

Comment: @Mico Possibly [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251158/9077)?

Comment: @Sverre -- Correct. (Our comments came in within seconds of each other.)

Comment: @Mico egreg's answer there provides a solution to this one too, so I'll go ahead and post an answer.

Comment: You may also want to post a bug report to the lualatex and/or luaotfload lists.

Comment: @Mico I don't think that LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX process the argument to `\url` in different ways.

Comment: @egreg - I may well have expressed myself poorly. What I meant to say is that XeLaTeX uses oldstyle figures for both `1234567890` and `\url{1234567890}`, whereas LuaLaTeX uses oldstyle figures only for the former, but not the latter (using the OP's preamble for setup).

Comment: @Mico I'm not on any of these mailing lists, so I'd leave that to someone who is ... ?

Comment: @Mico Yes, but the reason is very different: the processing is exactly the same, but `luaotfload` ignores the font's attribute when it's used in math mode.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks, now I get it: the problem isn't with LuaLaTeX but with `luaotfload`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question was asked in [How to make the `url` package respect fontspec font options (stylisticset) with LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250619/how-to-make-the-url-package-respect-fontspec-font-options-stylisticset-with), and egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251158/9077) with a following [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250619/how-to-make-the-url-package-respect-fontspec-font-options-stylisticset-with#comment598637_251158) provide the solution for this as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
    \urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Libertine Serif}[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]

\makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{%
        \do\0{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\0}}%
        \do\1{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\1}}%
        \do\2{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\2}}%
        \do\3{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\3}}%
        \do\4{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\4}}%
        \do\5{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\5}}%
        \do\6{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\6}}%
        \do\7{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\7}}%
        \do\8{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\8}}%
        \do\9{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\9}}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\url{http://example.com/1234567890}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For what it's worth, @egreg considers this to be [a bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251158/9077).

Comment: Yes, it definitely is a bug. Or, at least, an undesired feature. `;-)`

Comment: By the way, there is an issue already opened about this: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/204

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patch to modify the font used by `url` to be configured to use so called `base` mode in `LuaTeX+luaotfload` lingua. Indeed by default text fonts are declared using `node` mode, which (quote) `does not work in math mode` whatever that means. The patch modifies the font name to replace `mode=node` if present by `mode=base`.

But... in the example below I get the Old Style Figures to work, but the `tnum` (Tabular Figures) feature does not.

More experimenting reveals that it works separately for one feature (be it `Numbers=OldStyle` or `Numbers=Monospaced` or `Numbers=Proportional` but not with two at the same time; naturally I checked that the font name is correctly prepared in all cases).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Numbers = {OldStyle, Monospaced}]
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\makeatletter
\ifx\directlua\undefined\else
\begingroup
\catcode`N 12
\catcode`O 12
\catcode`D 12
\catcode`E 12
\lowercase{\gdef\FixFontForMath@i #1=NODE;#2#3\relax #4\@empty}%
  {%
  \ifx#2\empty
      \let\FixedFontForMath\font
  \else\font\FixedFontForMath=#1=base;#2#3\relax\fi 
  }%
\lowercase{\gdef\FixFontForMath {\expandafter\FixFontForMath@i
    \fontname\font\relax\relax=NODE;\empty\relax\@empty }}%
\endgroup
\def\Url@FormatString{%
 \UrlFont \FixFontForMath \Url@MathSetup 
 $\fam\z@ \textfont\z@\FixedFontForMath
 \expandafter\UrlLeft\Url@String\UrlRight
 \m@th$%
% \if\urldebug \showlists \fi 
}%
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}

http://www.0123456789.org (text)

\url{http://www.0123456789.org} (url)

\hsize 6cm

For some reason the `Tabular' feature is not obeyed in math. But the `Old Style'
feature now is.

\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

[image]

Comment: +tnum doesn't work in mode=base regardless if you are in math or not (for oldstyle number, normal numbers are lining anyway).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tested with `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Numbers = {Monospaced}]` in the code above and I do get tabular figures in `\url`, and the mode=base.

Comment: Do you get non-tabular figures somewhere if you remove the Numbers=Monospaced?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer to get non-tabular figures with TeX Gyre Termes I need to use Numbers = Proportional. Then I do get them. With my code above and `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Numbers = {Proportional}]` the text and url are exactly identical and use proportional figures.